# IP Forwarding / Masking

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I have a domain that I am forwarding to a server.  I got the domain though godaddy and it has the option to forward, or forward with masking.  I choose to forward with masking as just forwarding would result in a url with the IP of the server.  for example:

```
192.121.1.1/html/index.html
```

whereas forwarding with masking would result in the domain showing up rather than the IP but it would not reflect navigation in the URL.  for example

```
domainName.com/
```

but then on navigating to another page i would still get the same base url when I would expect something more like

```
domainName.com/path/to/file.html
```

One issue with this is that on refresh from ANY page on the site it would load the `domainName.com` page rather than the one the user meant to refresh.

What can someone explain what forwarding an IP address does?  And what masking it does?  Is there a way to avoid this behavior and simply get the domain name *with*  the path to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the "forward with masking" means that the go-daddy server is always active - providing a "hidden frame" to the client for that web page.  The frame is managed on the go-daddy server, and the frame itself just loads your actual *visual* page.  This usually results in numerous problems -cert error warnings, issues when using multiple DNS hosts (particularly when one is internal).

I'd stick with the forward *without* masking.  Just create an A-record in your sub-domain (like server1.domainname.com. ) and make its IP address the address of the forwarded server.

The real issue here is the fact that a server is showing up with its IP address in the user's URL bar, and not its DNS name.  This means that you probably have a web app (or some component of your web app) that is calling the actual IP address.  You probably know this, but using a fixed IP address is a bad idea, and will lead to problems down the road - ***especially if you mask the URL bar***!

Answer (score 0):

We just encountered this same issue and it took a few minutes to figure out the solution - as was indicated in the prior answer, GoDaddy utilizes the frame mechanism however, for security (and without any explicit configuration on our part), our servers send back a header with the X-Frame-Options set to block (you can see this if you open a chrome debug window and look at the network packets). For this particular site, we run a sinatra based ruby application behind an nginx server. The solution for us was a modification of the nginx.conf file to remove the X-Frame-Options header from the outgoing response.
So, basically, on GoDaddy we have:
Domain: http://71.168.231.129:8903/mypage(forward with masking)

and in the nginx conf we have
        location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            **proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;**
            # pass to the upstream unicorn server mentioned above
            proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
        }